# converting class name and passing to another class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a function where I receive map as Class, everything works fine, but when I convert it to string, where map is something like 'IconNorth', convert it to "FieldNorth" and try to pass to another class constructor I get error.

```
public function newMap(map, x1:int, y1:int):void {
    var createMap = new map();
    list.push(createMap);
    addChild(createMap);
    var field = map.toString().split("Icon").join("Field");
    new Board(this[field]);

}
```

and the Board class

```
public class Board extends MovieClip {

public static var list:Array = new Array();

public function Board(field=null) {
    list.push(this);
    if  (field!=null) {
        addChild(new field());
    }
}
...
```

the error is

```
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property [class FieldNorth] not found on Map and there is no default value.
```

I also tried 'getDefinitionByName' but it gives similar error.
So how do I convert a class name with or without using string to another class name and pass it to constructor?

Comment: You will have to use `getDefinitionByName`.  You should also type your vars for better readability and compiler error checking.   Presumably the `map` parameter is of type `Class` and `field` is a String?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you'll need to get the full class, so you can't just use `CLass.toString()` - in your case that would produce the string: `"[class FieldNorth]"`

Use `getQualifiedClassName` to get the full string class:

```
 var classStr:String = flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName(map);
```

Then, to get the reverse, you'll have to use `getDefinitionByName`:

```
var myClass:Class = flash.utils.getDefinitionByName(classStr) as Class  
var inst = new myClass();
```

So, for your example, this is what your code should look like:

```
public function newMap(map:Class, x1:int, y1:int):void {
    var createMap:Object = new map();
    list.push(createMap);
    addChild(createMap);

    var fieldClassStr:String = flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName(map).replace("Icon","Field");

    try { //if getDefinitionByName fails, it will throw an exception, not return null
        var field:Class = flash.utils.getDefinitionByName(fieldClassStr) as Class  
        new Board(field);
    }catch(e:Error){}
}
```

---

```
public function Board(field:Class) {
    list.push(this);
    addChild(new field());
}
```

Comment: nop still getting same error as I tried before with `getDefinitionByName`.
error is: `TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert FieldNorth$ to flash.display.DisplayObject.`

Comment: I don't think there is any other way to do what you're asking.  Though really you should architect your application to not need to convert strings to classes and classes to string.

Comment: error is still the same with try catch, just this time its on compiler:
`1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type Class to an unrelated type flash.display:DisplayObject.`
on this line `addChild(new field());`

Comment: oh wait I forgot to add `new` word, so this time I think it's working. ty